User cannot access docker program anymore
I have setup a group to grant user access to run docker without sudo and it worked perfectly before.
However, today I found I can no longer run docker without sudo anymore. It kept giving out this error message: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/ben/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
I am certain that the docker daemon is running because if I run the command sudo docker ps, there won't be any error.
Could someone point out how to fix this? Thank you!
The output of cat /etc/group | grep docker is docker:x:999:ben ; And the way I setup the group is use this two commands sudo groupadd docker, sudo gpasswd -a $USER docker

What are the permissions on the docker socket?

Like this: srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Sep  3 16:29 /var/run/docker.sock

At one point you must have tried to set up Docker Desktop (it shouldn't be necessary on a native-Linux system), which produces the $HOME/.docker/desktop path.  docker context use default will switch back to the standard setup.
